# Scrapyd Post schedule.json from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, scrapy, scrapyd

I have scrapyd and spider installed on a Unix machine, and everything works fine when  I run

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider
```

I can see the job status,logs and items on web interface of scrapyd API. in short everything is working as expected.

Now I want to start a spider programmatically by making a http post to the API in ASP.Net using C# as scrapyd will be part of my .NET project but I get

```
{"status": "error", "message": "'project'"}
```

I have found an example http://mahmoud.abdel-fattah.net/2012/07/04/super-simple-and-basic-scrapyd-web-interface/comment-page-1/ it makes a Jquery post and this example works for me but below one is not working for me

```
public void StartCrawler()
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mydomain.com:6800/schedule.json");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            //httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json;; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"project\":\"projectname\",\"spider\":\"spidername\"}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

please tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by

```
public static string StartCraling(string URI, string Parameters)
        {
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(URI);

            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.Method = "POST";

            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
            req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
            }

            using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the format of the Parameter object? Is it Json?